# Latest git tag not appearing with git describe command

Tags: git, github

Currently our CI builds on the latest git tag, `git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1)`

We have a scenario where a remote dev is tagging but the tag is only appearing with the command

```
git describe --abbrev=0
```

the tag is not appearing with the first command.

Answer (score 1):

`git rev-list --tags` will list every commit reachable from any tag, *in reverse chronological order*.  Adding `--max-count=1` limits the output to the first commit that would otherwise be displayed.  So that command shows the newest commit that has a tag.

If any user tags a commit, but it's not newer than every commit that already has a tag, it won't show.  I'm guessing, for your usage, that this sounds ok -- though do note that's newest *commit*, not newest *tag*.

Your remote dev, though... is his clock in sync with your local clock?

You might be able to improve the situation by adding the `--topo-order` flag, which ensures that a commit cannot be listed until all of its children have been listed.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get the git latest tag from the current branch your in. I just mentioned only simple approaches.

Answer to your question most simple way is to use this will provide the latest git tag

```
 $ git describe --tags
```

and another simple approach which you already mentioned your doing that

```
$ git describe --tags --abbrev=0
```